How to list all topics of deviceToken (ID service firebase deprecated)
IID api from fcm - https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/IIDtoken allows to look for all topics subscribed by devicetoken. Currently since it deprecated its responding with - "Authentication using server key is deprecated. Please use OAuth2token instead."
Post generating valid OAuth2 token as well it says request Unauthorized.
Can someone please suggest whats the alternative. I have tried firebase admin sdk apis mentioned here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics.
Firebase SDK does not have alternative api to list all topics from user deviceToken.
I have also tried to execute - pubsub.projects.topics.list api as mentioned here - https://www.any-api.com/googleapis_com/pubsub/docs/projects/pubsub_projects_topics_list. This as well didnt seems to work.
Please suggest of listing topic from user deviceToken is been fully removed post IID service is depricated.

Set this parameter in the header.
access_token_auth: true.
details: set this query parameter to true to get FCM topic subscription information (if any) associated with this token.
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/IIDtoken?details=true

I managed to get it working like this:

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/subscriptions")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSubscriptions(
            [FromHeader(Name = "x-fcm-token")][RequiredAttribute]
            string fcmToken, [FromServices] HttpClient httpClient,
            [FromServices] IConfiguration config
        )
        {
            var token = await GetAccessTokenAsync();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.RequestUri = new Uri($"https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/{fcmToken}?details=true");
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("access_token_auth", "true");
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var responseJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(responseContent);


            try
            {
                var topics = responseJson.GetProperty("rel").GetProperty("topics").EnumerateObject().Select(e => e.Name);

                
                return new JsonResult(topics);
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                return new JsonResult(new string[] { });
            }
        }


        public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                // Load the service account key from the JSON file
                GoogleCredential credential;
                using (var stream = new FileStream("google-creds.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                        .CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging");
                }

                // Create a JWT token for authentication
                var token = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();

                return token;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error obtaining access token: " + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }


You would need to manage topic subscriptions on the server side by keeping track of which topics a device token is subscribed to in your own database.
always manage and track form server side.

True, since there was an existing api which listing all topics of user, ask is do we have any alternative api for the same from FCM.
